# Python 3 classes error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to make a little program by using classes. So far, I've made two classes, in which the first one will run the next one. When I run this, I get an error message. I don't understand what's wrong, but it looks like it has something do to about that I define the name `Menu1` before it's been read. I'm going to create a new function after these classes, that'll first run `MainWindow`, and then `Menu1`. I would appreciate help.

Code:

```
class MainWindow:
    app = Tk()
    app.title("MyApp")
    window = Frame(app, width=1050, height=550)
    app.minsize(width=1050, height=550)
    window.pack()
    menu = Menu1()
    menu.makeMenu()
    app.mainloop()


class Menu1:
    def makeMenu(self):
        app.config(menu=menu)
        menu.add_cascade(label="Settings", menu=subMenu)
        subMenu.add_command(label="Settings", command=settings1)

def settings1():
    print("Open new window")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainWindow()
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 7, in <module>
    class MainWindow:
  File "", line 13, in MainWindow
    menu = Menu1()
NameError: name 'Menu1' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything under `class MainWindow` is run *immediately*. It is not in a method. At that point `class Menu1` has not yet been executed and no class by that name exists yet.

It looks like you really only wanted `MainWindow` to be a *function* instead:

```
def main_window():
    app = Tk()
    app.title("MyApp")
    window = Frame(app, width=1050, height=550)
    app.minsize(width=1050, height=550)
    window.pack()
    menu = Menu1()
    menu.makeMenu()
    app.mainloop()
```

(I used a lowercase letter this time, as the [Python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) reserves camel-case names for classes).

Your next problem is that `Menu1.makeMenu()` has no access to the `app` local variable in `main_window()`; you would need to pass that in:

```
menu = Menu1()
menu.makeMenu(app)
```

and

```
class Menu1:
    def makeMenu(self, app):
        app.config(menu=self)
        menu.add_cascade(label="Settings", menu=subMenu)
        subMenu.add_command(label="Settings", command=setting1)
```

Note that I changed `menu` to `self` there, `menu` was another local name in `main_window`.

The code still won't work because you haven't defined the name `subMenu` anywhere, but this is at least a step or 2 closer.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll go back look a little more at my earlier testing files as well.

Comment: Is there anyway to make this work without removing the first class?

Comment: @Andreas: Sure, take a look at http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-hello-again.htm on how to use classes properly. You are not really using classes correctly here.